# Stop one animation but keep alternating the other animation in CSS

Tags: css

There are two animations, fade in from left, and alternating glow. How to keep the alternating glow running but stop the fade in after one run?

```
.module{-webkit-animation:  fadeinwhileglowing 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;}

@keyframes fadeinwhileglowing {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
    transform: translateX(-40px);
  }

  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 25px #fff
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #fff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the two animations and give `animation` multiple `keyframes`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `glow` animation as it looks a bit funky in Firefox but I hope this example illustrates the solution.

*(I removed some of the vendor prefixes to make it easier to read. Add them back in your production code)*

```css
.module {
  animation: fadein 2s ease-in-out infinite,
             glow 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-40px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes glow {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 15px #fff, 0 0 25px #fff
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 40px #fff
  }
}

/* To make the glow visible */
body { background: #000 }
```

```html
<div class="module">Fade me and glow me!</div>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't expect the help, thank you very much! Finally it works. It is for a button, that would fade in from left and then glimmers, thus I would not run 'fadein' infinite but 'glow' infinite. Thank you!